# Internal Name for the Name(linked with document with edit menu) field SharePoint form library 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am creating a form library(info-path) view using power-shell command. One of the fields the view should contain is the Name(linked with document with edit menu). I want to know  this columns internal name.

I checked in U2U caml query builder, these are the following name i found which might be related to it

```
BaseName
FileLeafRef
LinkFileName
LinkFileName2
LinkFilenameNoMenu
Title
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to get an understanding of how the XLV works. Create a view in the GUI with the three different Name fields, i.e.

- Name (linked to document with Edit Menu)
- Name (for use in Forms)
- Name (linked to document)

Then open that page with SharePoint Designer and study the XLV. You will see that the three fields included in the order above appear in the XML definition as

```
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/>
    <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef"/>
    <FieldRef Name="LinkFilenameNoMenu"/>
</ViewFields>
```

If you customise and reveal the full XSL, you will see that all three fields actually refer to thisNode/@FileLeafRef, but that different XSL templates are applied to render the columns.

The XSL templates will introduce the appropriate tags and/or Javascript to include the link and/or the Edit Control Block (the edit drop-down).

I don't know which steps you take to create a view with PowerShell, but it looks like "LinkFilename" is the one you're after.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you are looking for LinkFileName. Basically you are looking for a field in the list that has the [ListItemMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.listitemmenu.aspx) property set to true.

To run a quick powershell you could do something like this ( assuming you already have your SPList):

```
$splist.Fields | Where-Object {$_.ListItemMenu -eq $true } | Select InternalName
```

Answer (score 2):

[SharePoint Manager 2010](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/51438) is always a good way to go, cause you can also retrieve the schema XML from each SPField or the SPListItem XML and analyse all internal info such as fields internal names and values.

spregards!

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Online uses `LinkFilename` without capital **N**, so watch out there.

`FileLeafRef` does not provide a link to the document in the view, while `LinkFilename` and `LinkFilenameNoMenu` does!